# How can I find $ARE_{\hat{\theta}_{n}^{(1)},\hat{\theta}_{n}^{(2)}}$ (in terms of $\tau_1$, $\tau_2$ and $\alpha$)?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, convergence, asymptotics, efficiency

Given that $n^{\alpha}[\hat{\theta}_{n}^{(1)}−\theta_0] \xrightarrow{L} \tau_1 H$ and $n^{\alpha}[\hat{\theta}_{n}^{(2)}−\theta_0] \xrightarrow{L} \tau_2 H$, find $ARE_{\hat{\theta}_{n}^{(1)},\hat{\theta}_{n}^{(2)}}$ (in terms of $\tau_1$, $\tau_2$ and $\alpha$).

This is what I tried:

We want $k_n[\delta_{n'}^{(2)}-g(\theta_0)] \xrightarrow{L} \tau_1H$

Since $n^\alpha[\hat{\theta}_n^{(2)}-\theta_0]\xrightarrow{L}\tau_2H$

$\Rightarrow \frac{\tau_1}{\tau_2}n^{\alpha}[\hat{\theta}_n^{(2)}-\theta_0]\xrightarrow{L}\tau_1H$

$\Rightarrow (\frac{\tau_1}{\tau_2}n)^{\alpha}[\hat{\theta}_{\frac{\tau_1}{\tau_2}n}^{(2)}-\theta_0]\xrightarrow{L}\tau_2H$ because we can use $n'$ to represent $\frac{\tau_1}{\tau_2}n$

$\Rightarrow (n)^{\alpha}[\hat{\theta}_{n'}^{(2)}-\theta_0]\xrightarrow{L} (\frac{\tau_1}{\tau_2})^{-\alpha}\tau_2H$

Since $n^{\alpha}[\hat{\theta}_{n}^{(1)}−\theta_0] \xrightarrow{L} \tau_1 H$

By the theorem, if $\sqrt{n}(\delta_n^{(1)}-g(\theta))\xrightarrow{L}N(0, \tau_1^2)$ and $\sqrt{n}(\delta_n^{(2)}-g(\theta))\xrightarrow{L}N(0, \tau_2^2)$ then $ARE_{\delta^{(1)},\delta^{(2)}}=\frac{\tau_2^2}{\tau_1^2}$

So, $$ARE_{\hat{\theta}_n^{(1)},\hat{\theta}_n^{(2)}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\tau_2^2}{\tau_1^2}=\frac{(\frac{\tau_1}{\tau_2})^{-2\alpha}\tau_2^2}{\tau_1^2}=(\frac{\tau_2}{\tau_1})^{2\alpha+2}$$

I realized I made some mistakes, so I made some corrections. But I am still not sure about it. Thanks!

Comment: Could you define what $ARE$ is?

Comment: ARE is Asymptotic Relative Efficiency. 

Definition of ARE: If $_[\delta_^{(1)}−(\theta_0)]\xrightarrow{L}$ and  $_[\delta_{'}^{(2)}−(\theta_0)]\xrightarrow{L}$, then $_{\delta_^{(1)},\delta_^{(2)}}=\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{′()}{}$
, $n'(n)$ is some function of n which is from the subscription of $\delta_{'}^{(2)}$